# Anylogic send a new order using getNearestAgentByRoute

Tags: agent, anylogic

Distribution centers (agent) will send a work order to manufacturing centers (agents at multiple locations on GIS map)

At a distribution agent, i added codes below

```
TestOrder testorder = new TestOrder (this);
```

// "this" is location of a distribution agent

```
send (testorder, getNearestAgentByRoute(main.manufacturingcenters));
```

// send the testorder to the nearest agent

Then i set up "enter" in the manufacturing center agent with Agent type, TestOrder.

However, there is no input in the simulation and shows an error on the code below

```
send (testorder, getNearestAgentByRoute(main.manufacturingcenters));
```

Answer (score 0):

- "this" is the distribution agent, not the location of the distribution agent... `testOrder(this)` means that your testOrder agent has a parameter which is a distribution agent.. is that correct? If not, you have a problem there... I'm assuming that testOrder is an agent type, otherwise you wouldn't be able to send anything with the send function.
- `send (testorder, getNearestAgentByRoute(main.manufacturingcenters);` is missing a parenthesis at the end. That's one reason you are getting an error.
- If you have an enter element from the process modeling library, to generate an agent in the enter block you need to do `enter.take(agent);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I set up the system as you mentioned at 1 and 2. I got this error message "  manufacturingcenters can't be resolved to a variable"

Comment: because manufacturingcenters is probably an agent type.. and not a population of agents... 
that's one possibility... but it can be many other things

Comment: manufacturingcenters is a population of agents created by GISpointcollections.  hm,,, the simulation works flawlessly but only the testorder is not captured in a manufactoring center.  I'll look into it and update if there is something else  Thanks!